# Event.target not working when clicked outside of the div to close it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a main div and the sub div which is also called form because form is wrapped inside of div. I want is to close the form when clicked outside of the main div but it's not happening at all. Please help me how to fix this.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('opener');
var box = document.getElementById('abc');
var form = document.getElementById('def');

btn.onclick = function(){
 box.style.display = "block";
}

//Doesn't work. It's function is to close the form when click outside of the div.
window.onclick = function(event){
 if(event.target == box){
   form.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#abc{
  display: none;
  background-color: #F44336;
}
```

```html
 <button id = "opener">
  Open
  </button>
  <div id = "abc">
  <!-- Login Authentication -->
  <div id = "def">
   <div>
    <p>Welcome</p>
   </div>
   <br />
   <div class = "login-auth" id = "cool">
     <form method="POST">
  <label>Email or Username:</label>
  <input type = "text">
  <br />
  <label>Password:</label>
  <input type = "password">
  <br /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Login">
 </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

JSFiddle Link Here: https://jsfiddle.net/twrvpp3d/

Comment: If you simply put `console.log(event.target);` in the click handler you would see the problem.

Comment: Take a look --> https://jsfiddle.net/twrvpp3d/9/

Comment: Thanks @UncaughtTypeError for the answer. But the problem is already solved though :D

Comment: Yea, I was a tad too late :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is working fine, the only problem that you need to stop the click event from propagating by using `e.stopPropagation()` for the button and the popup window, this will create the desired effect! Refer my below snippet!

```
#def{
  border:1px solid black;
}
#abc{
  padding:40px;
}
```

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('opener');
var box = document.getElementById('abc');
var form = document.getElementById('def');

btn.onclick = function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  box.style.display = "block";
}
box.onclick = function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
}

//Doesn't work. It's function is to close the form when click outside of the div.
window.onclick = function(event) {
    box.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#abc {
  display: none;
  background-color: #F44336;
}

#def {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#abc {
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<button id="opener">
  Open
</button>
<div id="abc">
  <!-- Login Authentication -->
  <div id="def">
    <div>
      <p>Welcome</p>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="login-auth" id="cool">
      <form method="POST">
        <label>Email or Username:</label>
        <input type="text">
        <br />
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="password">
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: BUT STILL DOESN'T CLOSES WHEN CLICKED OUTSIDE OF DIV. CLOSES ONLY WHEN CLICKED ON PADDING AREA.

Comment: @John The OP only seems to want to close when `event.target == box`. The only way to click on that is to click on the padding

Comment: That's it! Thanks @NarenMurali and Barmer

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not what you are asking but can you make toggle button? its easier to do and more obvious for user.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('opener');
var box = document.getElementById('abc');
var form = document.getElementById('def');

btn.onclick = function(e){
    
    
    if(e.target.innerHTML === 'Open'){
     box.style.display = "block";
     e.target.innerHTML = "Close"
    }else{
      box.style.display = "none";
     e.target.innerHTML = "Open"
    }
 
}

//Doesn't work. It's function is to close the form when click outside of the div.
window.onclick = function(event){
 if(event.target == box){
   form.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#abc{
  display: none;
  background-color: #F44336;
}
```

```html
 <button id = "opener">
  Open
  </button>
  <div id = "abc">
  <!-- Login Authentication -->
  <div id = "def">
   <div>
    <p>Welcome</p>
   </div>
   <br />
   <div class = "login-auth" id = "cool">
     <form method="POST">
  <label>Email or Username:</label>
  <input type = "text">
  <br />
  <label>Password:</label>
  <input type = "password">
  <br /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Login">
 </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I am sorry but this is not how i want the things to happen. Thank you for your answer. Also, to do this, we don't have to type long code as you did. Just simply, make a CSS class and toggle it via Javascript :)

Comment: Yeah,thats just quick example which doesnt even work properly :D

Answer (score 0):

`window.onclick` does not work on certain browsers. Try `document.onclick` instead.

Comment: Do you have a reference for `window.onclick` not working? Even if it's true, that's not the real problem here, and switching to `document` won't help.